# Ninject BeginLifeTimeScope

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

Is there a Ninject equivalent of the following code that uses Autofac:

```
    public T Create<T>()
    {
        var requestScope =
            container.BeginLifetimeScope(
                builder => builder.RegisterType(typeof(T)).AsSelf());

        var viewModel = requestScope.Resolve<T>();

        lock (viewModelToContainersSyncLock)
        {
            viewModelsToContainers[viewModel] = requestScope;
        }

        return viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: I know next to nothing about Autofac, but that code doesn't look right.  Isn't BeginLifetimeScope supposed to be disposed after you have have used the object?  That looks like a memory leak waiting to happen.  In any event, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with that code, so I don't really know how to give you an equivalent in Ninject.

Comment: I have a realase method too to this. I call the create if I navigate to a View and I bind the created VM to that but after I dont need it, I release VM. I just want to know that if there an equivalent code for BeginLifetimeScope in Ninject is or not.

Comment: So you have to remember to release it?  That defeats the purpose of a dependency injection framework.  That means your client is tightly bound to the DI framework, because it must know how to release it.  Whether or not Ninject has what you're looking for, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: But if I do something wrong, plase correct me. I want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you're trying to accomplish with this code.  What is its purpose?

Comment: I have a ViewModelFactory class. It hase a Create and a Release method too. Hier it is a a FrameNavigating and FrameNavigating event registered. VM or View doesnt know about the create or relaese. ViewModelLocator class uses this Factory and Locator is a Resource of App.xaml and all the Views can use it to bind VM. That was my idee behind this.

Comment: `var requestScope =
            container.BeginLifetimeScope(
                builder => builder.RegisterType(typeof(T)).AsSelf());

        var viewModel = requestScope.Resolve<T>();` 

is something like this in Ninject?

Comment: But WHY are you doing it this way? What is your reason for having this weird create/release mechanism, and why are you using Autofac as a service locator?  The point of dependency injection is that your code should virtually *NEVER* call Resolve.  If you're doing that, you're using it wrong.

Comment: Please do not just say I am wrong, it could be. I have a given code and I want to try using Ninject in this code insteed of autofac. If you have a good solution to resolve MainViewModel in a ViewModelLocator on the request:

`DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}}"`

just let me know it. Thx.

Comment: Since you continue to refuse to tell me what you are trying to achieve with this code, I simply cannot help you.  It's like trying to translate from one language to another when you don't understand the context the words are used in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AutoFac:**

You can create a lifetime scope by calling the BeginLifetimeScope() method on any existing lifetime scope, starting with the root container. Lifetime scopes are disposable and they track component disposal, so make sure you always call "Dispose()" or wrap them in "using" statements.

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  // Resolve services from a scope that is a child
  // of the root container.
  var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();

  // You can also create nested scopes...
  using(var unitOfWorkScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    var anotherService = unitOfWorkScope.Resolve<IOther>();
  }
}
```

**Ninject:**

There are four built-in scopes available in Ninject, and a number of others delivered via Extensions: [Object-Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

As far as i understand your question the most reasonable scope you are after is the ***InScope()***.
Then you can easily define your own scopes using the ***.InScope(Func selectScope)*** method.

You could create then something like this:

```
public class ScopeObject
{ }

public static class ProcessingScope
{
  public static ScopeObject Current {get; set;}
}

using Xunit;
public class NinjectCustomScopeExample
{
  public class TestService { }

  [Fact]
  public static void Test()
  {
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<ScopeObject>().ToSelf().InScope( x => ProcessingScope.Current );

    var scopeA = new ScopeObject();
    var scopeB = new ScopeObject();

    ProcessingScope.Current = scopeA;
    var testA1 = kernel.Get<ScopeObject>();
    var testA2 = kernel.Get<ScopeObject>();

    Assert.Same( testA2, testA1 );

    ProcessingScope.Current = scopeB;
    var testB = kernel.Get<ScopeObject>();

    Assert.NotSame( testB, testA1 );

    ProcessingScope.Current = scopeA;
    var testA3 = kernel.Get<ScopeObject>();

    Assert.Same( testA3, testA1 );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already forgot that I asked such a question. :) But thanks for the answer, it's a good, detailed description.